# Can't get Angular select to update with selected value

Tags: angularjs

I'm using selects to allow a user to switch between events and years. Each change will pull appropriate data from the server, return and update the page. However, the select box goes from the selected value to an empty value. I've looked at numerous solutions and they aren't working.

```
<select
   ng-model="eventName"
   ng-options="item.value for item in eventOptions track by item.value"
   ng-change="changeEvent(eventName.value)">
</select>
```

This is the changeEvent function:

```
$scope.changeEvent = function(eventName){
    $scope.eventName = eventName; //wrongly assumed this would update the selected value
    $scope.getData($scope.eventName,$scope.eventYear); //this returns the json - correct
    $scope.updateSelected(); //meant to update the select field value on the page - fails
};
```

$scope.eventName or $scope.eventYear values will properly update on a change, but has no effect on the page. The selects just empty of a selected value.

**UPDATED (with corrected code)**
I wanted to post the changes I made more clearly than the comment allows.

I removed the object param "value" from the options and the argument from the function call (eventName.value).

```
<select
    ng-model="eventName"
    ng-options="item for item in eventOptions track by item"
    ng-change="changeEvent()">
</select>
```

And the changeEvent function gets simplified to:

```
$scope.changeEvent = function(){
    $scope.getData($scope.eventName,$scope.eventYear);
};
```

It all works as expected! Thanks to all, especially Delta who got me looking at it the right way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, your event name variable is set to be `item`. not `item.value` so instead of passing in `changeEvent(eventName.value)` try passing in `changeEvent(eventName)`. either way the value you are passing into your method doesnt match the value of your model's variable

```
item.value for item in eventOptions track by item.value
```

so for this statement, you are saying make my options `ng-model=item` but make their  `value=item.value` so they show what you want them to show but still have all the information you need from each one.

Upon further inspection is looks like you dont need:

```
 $scope.eventName = eventName; 
 $scope.updateSelected();
```

Angular should be updating your eventName for you, you just need to call the change method.

Comment: This got me on the right path. I had to play around with the code a bit until I corrected for the new approach. I had been returning a named array ([label: 'Label Name', value: "Label Name']) for each option and building the options using the item.value. I simplified it to a simply value array and eliminated the need to ever specify the object parameter for those fields. This allowed me to simply use $scope.eventName or $scope.eventYear. My change event function is now $scope.changeEvent = function(){$scope.getData($scope.eventName,$scope.eventYear);};

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you need:

```
ng-change="changeEvent(eventName.value)"
```

if you use ng-options the model will be updated in the scope automatically on selection. You could watch the value in the controller if you want to do other stuff when it changes:

```
$scope.$watch('eventName', function() {
   //do stuff
});
```

Comment: this solution should work but comes with benefits and drawbacks, this watcher will fire even if the eventName is changed in the javascript, Which could be good or bad depending on the situation. The OP's method will only fire when the user changes the selects selection.

Comment: @Delta, true. I was just trying to show that an angular select updates the model in the scope for you without needing to track when the user changes the select.

Comment: @Delta, actually on second look if the value updated in the controller it would update the select anyway as it's bound to the model. So it amounts to the same thing.